# OracleCommand parameters on CHAR type columns

Tags: .net, sql, oracle

I am using OracleCommand.Parameters in a select query for on an Oracle 11g database.
The following statement works great on columns that are of type number or varchar.

```
string theQuery = "select * from TABLE where COLUMN = :p1";
OracleCommand Cmd = new OracleCommand(theQuery);
Cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p1", "2183989118"));
Cmd.Connection = Conn;
Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```

The problem is that I really want to run the statement against a column of type CHAR(20 BYTE), and when I do this i never get a result. The query works if I am not using parameters and just adding '2183989118' in theQuery directly.

Am i missing something in my Parameters.Add statement?

Comment: Are you sure there is no "     2183989118" value in COLUMN. new OracleParameter("p1",OracleDbType.Char);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
  Cmd.Parameters.Add("p1", OracleDbType.Char);
```

Comment: I ended up editing the Parameter like this:
Cmd.Parameters.Add("p1", OracleDbType.Char).Value = "2183989118";
Working great, thanks!